# How to create simple 2-page site using 2 markdown files in github pages?

Tags: github-pages

I am trying to make a very simple site in github pages that will only have two pages: a homepage and an about page.

I would like each of these pages to be generated from markdown files.

The homepage is easy, I just put the homepage markdown in README.md and it shows up at myusername.github.io

Is there a simple way to add a second markdown page?

I understand github pages uses jekyll and I can do this by creating an entire jekyll blog, but that seems like overkill for what I want to do. What's the simplest way to add a markdown file to the github repo and have a working url to a rendering of it.

This is not a blog. There will never be more than these two pages

Comment: Just read this and follow inststructions: https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/ That should be more than enough. It's not necessary to use Jekyll directly, github does it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### One can create `Multiple .MD Pages` on GH-Pages

1. Create a new file about.md
2. At the top of this file, add the following:

```
---
title: ABOUT PAGE
layout: template
filename: about.md
---
```

3. Link this `about.md` in our `Readme.md` file using:

```
Go to [about page](about.md)
```

4. Commit your changes and push them to the gh-pages branch

**Now, when you go to `YOURGITHUBNAME.github.io/YOURPROJECTNAME/about.md`, you should see the contents of your about.md formatted with the theme that you chose.**

Comment: Hello Amit, thank you for the answer it was very helpful, but can you please tell me how do I change the layout of that 2nd md file. Here you are using `template` as layout, but is there any other layout options available, I tried writing `Cayman` and `Dinky` but it did not work. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @SoumyadipSarkar Did you try setting these templates using **Choose template** option in settings or mentioning them in the `about.md` ?

Comment: You may want to also check out [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll)

Comment: I guess you are talking about the `change theme` option, I did, and an index.md and `_config.yml` got created, in that `_config.yml`, `jekyll-theme-cayman` was already set as theme. But as you mentioned, I tried setting from that link, as `theme: minima`, but the whole layout went blank and it was like a blank markup preview, [Link](https://soumya997.github.io/use-me/).

Comment: I believe we cannot do that unless we create two different repos with different themes. You can make use of `layouts` which you will need to define by yourself or derive from a jekyll theme. Here are some links to help you out: [Link 1](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/04-layouts/) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58290229/11608962) [Link 3](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jekyll/comments/ewa2i9/jekyll_newb_can_i_use_different_themes_for/fg15156/) [Link 4](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/jekyll-pages-novice/layouts/index.html)

Answer (score 8):

I solved the issue.

The key is to include this at the top of the about markdown

```
---
title: Title
---
```

This helps github pages know the page is a markdown file that needs to be rendered.

The about page can be placed in the repo in an about.md file, and linked to from the main README.md file

Answer (score 2):

just create a file `about.md` with the content.
than you can link from your `README.md` to your `about.md` like so:
`[YourLinkText For About](about.md)`

Comment: This doesn't work. This shows the raw text of the markdown without editing it